# Static vs non-static in Java in terms of memory state

Tags: java

1. Please help me to explain the concept of static vs non-static variable and method in terms of memory state diagram in Java. Or give me some books explaining this concept!
2. Also in terms of memory, When an object in created (without static keyword), each object will have its own member variables. But how about methods, do they have they own member methods in memory space?
3. Static methods can’t use non-static(regular) methods in terms of memory space.
   Thanks

Comment: The developers of the JVM do a lot of effort to save the user from such low level performance considerations. Therefor you should focus on *correctness*, *readability* and *extendability* of your code unless you have **proven by profiling** that a certain language feature is a performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ... the concept of static vs non-static variable ...

The word variable usually refers to a local variable in a method, which are instantiated during method activation, on the thread stack.  These cannot be declared static in Java (some languages like C allows it, but that is another matter).

In Java, only class members, which are fields & methods, may be declared static 
(i.e. not local variables).

Static fields belong directly to the class, and are initialized when the class is loaded and persist the duration of the class; there is only at most one of each static field in the whole program.  (I say at most because before the class is loaded then there are zero of its static fields.)

Instance (non-static) fields are initialized when an instance (an object of the class) is created and persist for the duration of the instance.  Each instance has its own (copy of) instance (non-static) fields.

> When an object in[sic] created (without static keyword), each object will have its own member variables.

True that each object will have its own copy of the instance fields.  But to be clear, objects are created using the `new` keyword, there is no concept of static here -- it is not possible to create a static object in Java, only static fields can be declared, though these can be references to instance (non-static) objects!

> Also in terms of memory ... But how about methods, do they have they own member methods in memory space?

Methods have two things: code and activations.  An activation represents the instantiation of the method; this is done at runtime by executing a method invocation construct; methods are activated rather than being created.

When a method is invoked, the method is activated by creating a frame (a stack frame) on the current thread's stack.  This activation holds, among other things, the values of the parameters passed by the invoker (along with knowledge of what to execute next when the method returns and its associated activation frame is removed from the thread stack).

The code exists as bytecode (and conceptually) only once per class, regardless of static vs. instance (non-static).

The difference is that instance methods must be invoked with what is sometimes called a receiver object, and have access to this instance (object) via the `this` keyword, whereas static methods cannot be invoked via a receiver, and hence do not have a `this` keyword available to them.

That means that the bytecode for instance methods provide for use of the `this` keyword, and an activation frame for an instance method contains a local variable that is used for the `this` parameter.  No matter who is doing the invocation of an instance method, during that invocation some receiver object must be provided.

In terms of memory space, instance methods effectively are given/take a "hidden" extra parameter, so the memory space shows up on the activation stack as an additional reference local variable.  (FYI, this is considered a relatively minor usage of space.)

> Static methods can’t use non-static(regular) methods in terms of memory space.

Static methods are never invoked using a receiver object, and thus do not have the `this` keyword available to them.  Fundamentally, this is the only difference: they can otherwise do anything that other methods can do, which includes invoking instance methods -- just as long as they don't use the `this` keyword.

Static methods may invoke instance methods if they otherwise obtain a reference to an instance.  This could be by passing them an explicit instance reference as a parameter, or they might locate an instance in some other way, e.g. following some data structure to an instance, or as a return value from some other method.  Of course, they may invoke instance methods of any type for which they have references to, provided the appropriate public/private access modifiers support this, just like other methods.  So, they can invoke methods using local variables (e.g. `x.ToString()`) The only limitation is that they cannot use the `this` keyword (e.g. `this.ToString()`).

(From a style point-of-view, however, static fields and methods are frowned upon, though since that is not your question, I will let you search on that.)

Answer (score 0):

Static data (fields and members) are loaded into memory on class loading and remain until the class is unloaded from memory (typically on JVM termination).

Regular data is created on instantiation of an object instance, and becomes eligible for garbage collection when the instance goes out of scope. When it is released from memory cannot be predicted as this depends on the garbage collector which might decide to not remove anything until memory gets to be below a certain limit that may or may not be reached before the JVM terminates.

How the JVM handles memory depends on the version and creator of the JVM (e.g. an Oracle JVM may do it different from an IBM one) and of course the target operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that demonstrates cases mentioned in your question:

```
public class Example {
    // each instance of Example has its own:
    String instanceField;
    // only one of these exists (per classloader):
    static String classField;

    String instanceMethod() {
        // Here we can access both members.
        // tmp is located in stack so each invocation of this method
        // has its own:
        String tmp = instanceField + classField;
        return tmp;
    }

    static String classMethod() {
        // Here we cannot access instanceField.
        // tmp is located in stack so each invocation of this method
        // has its own:
        String tmp = classField + ".";
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

The `tmp` variable as a *reference* is in the stack, but of course the String object is in the heap. Maybe that's outside scope here, and it's enough to just say that methods don't have "members", they just have a locally allocated area in the stack.